# Windows service OnStart not called on AWS EC2

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a windows service developed in C#.NET. It is installed on an AWS EC2 instance which is associated with an Elastic Beanstalk instance.

When I install the service and start, its OnStart event called successfully, I even tried restarting the server and this time also OnStart event of the windows service called successfully. Problem is when new EC2 instance is created by the load balancer (because previous instance was down) that time my service also get started but OnStart event was not called.

I am sure that OnStart was not called because I didn't get the expected result which supposed to be there after calling OnStart event.

Please help if you have any idea.

Comment: Have you tried to debug `OnStart()` call?

Comment: @AndreyMyatlyuk I have tried debugging on my development system but there is no way to debug on AWS EC2 instance that it too when load balancer is called and new instance allocated.

Comment: You cannot print something in the log? All you need to know is whether the method is called or not.

Comment: @AndreyMyatlyuk Yes, I have written logs in windows event and log file both but didn't get any thing in these logs.

Comment: Never? Can you please update your question with more details? Like what is happening in the event log/log file when you install the service? What is happening in the event log/log file when the instance is created by AutoScaling service?

Comment: I have already specified that when I installed and started service OnStart called successfully, it is also called when I restart the system. The only problem is then auto scaling creates new instance nothing happens.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43477/discussion-between-nikhil-and-andrey-myatlyuk)

Comment: Were you able to test a simple Windows service as we discussed in the chat?

Comment: How are you installing the service?

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the service to start automatically in Windows Services?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where a Windows Service configured to start automatically failed to start when the EC2 instance was booted.  Subsequently it was possible to start the service manually.

I then discovered that a Windows 2012 EC2 instance has [a Windows service Ec2Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2config-service.html) (*) that performs some important actions at startup, such as mounting EBS volumes and assigning drive letters.

I configured my service to have a dependency on Ec2Config, and since then it appears to be working perfectly.

(*) The name has changed to Ec2Launch in WIndows 2016.